# A bound for a real rational function

Tags: real-numbers

Let $r\geq 1, $ and $\theta$ be any real number. Then 
\begin{equation}\frac{1-r\cos\theta}{1+r^2-2r\cos\theta}\leq \frac{1}{2}.\end{equation}
For, wehave
$2\leq 1+r^2\implies2-2r\cos\theta\leq1+r^2-2r\cos\theta,$ which establishes the above inequality. 
The above inequality is sharp when $r=1,$ that is, when $r$ gets the least possible value. So for $r$  sufficiently larger than $1$, the gap between LHS and RHS widens. Is there any way of bettering this inequality by redefining the R.H.S by a function $f(r)$ where $f(1)=1/2?$ Kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Multiplying both sides by $$1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta)$$ we get
$$2-2r\cos(\theta)\le 1 +r^2-2r\cos(\theta)$$
Can you finish?
$$1-2r\cos(\theta)+r^2=(r-1)^2+2r(1-\cos(\theta))\geq 0$$

Comment: May I know what exactly you are suggesting?